# How many books remain in the Honor Harrington series?

Tags: honorverse

As of February 2015, there are 13 books. The latest is HH13 *A Rising Thunder*, and the story doesn't end there. How many books are still to come?

By *A Rising Thunder*,

> Honor is one of the most powerful character in the universe, she has everything that she can't possibly be rewarded anymore. She's at the very top, with no room left to grow. The RMN is practically untouchable. The story is devolving from space battles to political debates. Knowing that, the series got to get to close to end. There's nowhere for Honor Harrington to go but down.

Answer (score 6):

Author stated that he planned for HH to not survive First Battle of Manticore*. However, with all spin-offs it became if not impossible, then premature and certainly ill advised. This development was, obviously, unexpected and unforeseen.

No definite information yet as to her fate is available, so allow me to guess: there is coming one battle for the future of known galaxy as we know it by name of Honorverse... Fight to the death with invisible ships equipped with also previously unknown weapon...
And this will be the heroine's Trafalgar. So I'm fairly certain that no more than two books to go.

Of course, there is in the pipeline the "Heirs of Honor"-ish book, with her children or more distant descendant(s) as protagonist(s).

EDIT: *Second Battle of Manticore, according to some sources. First Battle of Manticore took place over 400 T-years before HH.

Comment: In the later books Honor seems to be modeling Lord Marlbourough from 1700s more than Lord Nelson from the 1800s - involved with politics and war, screwed over by the other party making a bad peace treaty.  Here though the Queen isn't the perpetrator.  And with the new threat of slavers, the historical flow is entirely out the window.  So there's no real saying, although having Honor fight hand to hand might fade away as they have in the last several tomes.

Comment: Yes, she does. However, "Honor's Trafalgar" is not my term. Author himself is the author.

However it will be fun to see what the development there will be.

Comment: note on edit: yes, the First battle of Manticore is Operation Beatrice, lead by Tourville. It doesn't make any sense that HH was going to be killed at the Second one, so you are probably right.

Comment: I think Weber has stated that the stories that were going to be about Honor's children have been adapted into the Crown of Slaves and Saganami Island series (the latter of which has merged into the main line with SI3 (Shadow of Freedom) also being considered HH14. Other characters have taken the place of Honor's children and the whole timeline moved up by several decades.

Comment: Obviously necessary in light of the way things developed in the spin-offs. Weber "complained" that not maintaining control on them others (too much creative freedom) caused massive changes to his own main line events timetable - by which I mean the projected end of HH series waaaay earlier. But to be clear I'm not complaining - right now on book 2 of Manticore Ascendant... And considering the SoS books as good as the main line.

Answer (score 6):

It's unclear how many books remain, but here's some info from a recent interview.

> “I am, honestly, planning on wrapping up a series in 2018, which will happen to be the 25th anniversary of Basilisk Station, and will finally tie up the storyline that I had in mind when I started that book.  It doesn’t mean the end of the Honorverse, it just means that I will finish that storyline."

-- David Weber, [Baen Free Radio Hour 2016-03-18](http://www.baen.com/podcastfiles/mp3/Baen-Free-Radio-Hour-2016-03-18-Weber-Presby-2-Graveyard-41.mp3) (54:53-55:25)

Comment: HH14 was published in 2018 Oct (https://honorverse.fandom.com/wiki/Uncompromising_Honor), and does more or less do what Weber described as his plan.  Still room for the side stories to continue, e.g. Crown of Slaves 4 is planned for 2021 Oct.  Or even for the main storyline to resume later, with the next generation.  Also, of course the prequel series have their own storylines. Star Kingdom (Stephanie Harrington) still has another novel planned, as does Manticore Ascendant (Travis Long, Lisa Donnelly, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

According to the author's own web page and the Honor Wikias, there are 14 Books in main line with projection of 5 books left in main line and 5 more in each spin off line. What route that will take is not clear. This does not preclude the creation of more spin off lines to go back in time like the Manticore asecendant spin off...like maybe a Beowulf Chronicles.

Comment: Sounds great but, OTOH, there were projections earlier as well. For example Author never predicted the impact the CoS and/or SoS spin-offs on the main line.
In other words: great and that, but only way to be sure is to wait and see ;)

Answer (score -1):

Should be at least two more with Honor's death coming at end of the second in a successful attack on the alignment headquarters (hand to hand with Detwillers bodyguard?).

Comment: Do you actually have anything to support this?